# Why is $|x-x_0|^k$ decreasing in k as x gets closer to $x_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

This question related to the Taylor Series. The statement is:
If f ∈ $C^{k+1}$ (A, R), then $lim _{x->x_0}|R_k(x)/ (x-x_0)^{k+1}|< ∞$.

1. Why do we not say $R_{k+1}$?
2. I read that as x gets closer to $x_0$, $|x-x_0|^k$ is going to decrease in k, hence the higher the k, the higher is the accuracy. What does this exactly mean? What does decreasing in k mean?

Comment: 1. We say $R_k$ because it is the remainder if we take the taylor-expansion of degree n, this is always a degree higher than n. For 2. I could only guess, that if $|x-x_0|<0$ then increasing $k$ decreases the expression. Where did you read it? Maybe it becomes clear from the context.

Answer (score 0):

When $0<|x-x_0|<1$, then
$$
  |x-x_0|^k = \exp\big(\log |x-x_0| \cdot k \big).
$$
Since $\log |x-x_0|< \log(1) < 0$, the function $k \mapsto \log |x-x_0| \cdot k$ is decreasing. Since $z\mapsto \exp(z)$ is a strictly increasing function, it preserves monotonicity, thus
$$
 k \mapsto \exp\big(\log |x-x_0| \cdot k \big)
$$
is decreasing.